# Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany() return first()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel 5.5 application and I have the following models.

- Jobs
- JobSheets
- Users

I have a relation on my Users model

```
public function jobs() {
  $this->hasMany('App\Job','user_id')->with('jobSheets');
}
```

I have a relation on my Jobs model

```
public function jobSheets() {
  $this->belongsToMany('App\JobSheet','jobs_jobsheets','job_id','sheet_id');
}
```

I'm trying to return all my current logged in users' jobs with the latest job sheet.

A job can have many job sheets but I only want to return the latest.

I've tried in my controller

```
return Auth::user()->jobs;
```

However that returns all the jobs sheets against the job.

I've also tried creating another method on my job model.

```
public function latestJobsheet()
{
  return $this->jobsheets->first();
}
```

and amending my jobs method on the user model to:

```
public function jobs() {
  $this->hasMany('App\Job','user_id')->with('latestJobsheet');
}
```

but I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()

Comment: How do you determine the latest job sheet? Highest id?

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Comment: @Dev.Wol did you find a way to get the first job sheet only?

Answer (score 2):

You could split the `BelongsToMany` relationship and add a model for the pivot table (`jobs_jobsheets`):

```
class Job {

    public function latestJobSheetPivot() {
        return $this->hasOne(App\JobSheetPivot::class)->orderBy('sheet_id', 'DESC');
    }

}

class JobSheetPivot {

    protected $table = 'jobs_jobsheets';

    public function jobSheet() {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\JobSheet::class);
    }

}

class User {

    public function jobs() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Job::class)->with('latestJobSheetPivot.jobSheet');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `jobs_jobsheets` table contains an `id` column it would probably be best to order the jobSheets returned from newest to oldest.

Here's what that would look like:

```
public function jobSheets()
{
  $this->belongsToMany('App\JobSheet','jobs_jobsheets','job_id','sheet_id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
```

If you want to limit the number of results returned you can chain `->limit($num_results)` to the end of the `belongsToMany` method

Comment: `limit()` breaks eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `$with` property on your `Job` model and have it eager load the relation `latestJobsheet`. From there, when you access the `jobs` relation on your `User` model, you should have the latest job sheet available to you. How you determine the latest job sheet is a separate matter.

Comment: Code example please ?